# pinging multiple users in discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to "@" specific members after issuing a command, the following doesn't seem to work.

```
from tokens.token import discord_token
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!",intents = intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")

@client.command
async def play(ctx):
    paul = get(ctx.guild.members, name = 'paul')
    john = get(ctx.guild.members, name = 'john')
    await ctx.send("f{paul.mention} {john.mention} lets play games!")
    
client.run(discord_token)
```

It should return something like

```
MyBotName: @john @paul lets play games!
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to enable intents, for more info refer to:  https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html also make sure to enable privileged member intents.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński After adding intents, I still get the error ```Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mention'```

Comment: I see that you actually have some intents enabled, though you're missing `intents.members`, as I said in my comment above, make sure to enable them

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Is there a way to loop over multiple people and mention them?  Instead of manually specifying the get?

Comment: What do you mean by "loop over multiple people"? You mean loop over a list of member names/IDs?

Comment: Yes, also would it be better to use IDs? If so what is correct syntax?

Comment: `@client.command()` instead of `@client.event` before `async def play(ctx):`

Comment: Yes, a lot better is to use IDs, you can simply look over the list and `Guild.get_member`, if you can use the raw mention format: `<@!{user_id}>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used f-string wrong in your code. f must be come before the string:

```
await ctx.send(f"{paul.mention} {john.mention} lets play games!")✅
await ctx.send("f{paul.mention} {john.mention} lets play games!")❌
```

Also if you didn't enable intents, go to the developer portal and enable intents. Then add it to your bot's properties with:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", discord.Intents.all()) # or what you need
```